# How to get time average

Tags: php, average

I have a time calculations problem in getting average.

I have this summed up call time 06:03:05 and I want to get an average with 175 calls.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $ts =  strtotime("06:03:05");
    echo date("H:i:s", $ts/175);
```

I get:
12:26:25

I'm not even sure why I come up with this very huge time average. Am I doing this right? Please help.

Comment: You cannot use `$ts` like an integer to compute `$ts/175`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that your `strtotime` call, not having a date component, is defaulting to the current date. So the `$ts` is a much *much* larger number than just the sum of the time parts; it includes the date parts as well.

I would avoid using the time functions like that. It's simple enough to calculate the number of seconds based on the hours, minutes and seconds. Once you have that, you can use `date()` to echo the formatted time like you do there.

Try something more like this:

```
function getTimeAverage($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $division) {
    $seconds += ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60);
    return $seconds / $division;
}

$average = getTimeAverage(6, 3, 5, 175);

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $average);
```

Comment: it must be `gmdate('H:i:s', $average);`. but this only works up to 24 hours.

Comment: Good point, thanks for that. I've edited the answer. - I live on GMT, so I tend to forget timezone issues like these :)

Comment: oh.. I get it now.. THANKS A LOT GUYS... Atli and redreggae

Answer (score 0):

One easy way which only works up to 24 hours. Else take Atlis approach and search also for a way to convert seconds to date.

```
$time = '06:03:05';
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
$average = $seconds/175;
echo gmdate('H:i:s', $average);
```